# Dart - Getting RangeError involving iteration over a list of numbers

Tags: math, dart

I'm using Dart, trying to do some low level project euler problems; this problem is for both the prime number counter and greatest prime factor problem.

Here is the Unit Test and the error below which is produced (my other two unit tests evaluate fine):

```dart
test('evaluate if target is not factorable', () {
  // Arrange
  var maximum = 14;
  var control_list_of_primes = <int>[2,3,5,7,11];
  var test_list_of_primes = <int>[2,3,5,7,11];
  // Act
  prime_list_expansion(maximum, test_list_of_primes);
  // Assert
  expect(test_list_of_primes[-1] == 13, true);
});
```

```
ERROR: -prime factor generator- should evaluate if target is not factorable

Test failed: Caught RangeError: -1
List.[]
```

Here is the function `prime_list_expansion` (the functions it calls pass the tests I've designed for them so I don't think they are the problem):

```dart
prime_list_expansion (int maximum, List prime_list) {
  var start = prime_list[-1];
  for (var i = start; i < maximum; i = i+2) {
    if (target_not_factorable (i, prime_list)) {
      prime_list.add(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
expect(test_list_of_primes[-1] == 13, true);
```

and

```
var start = prime_list[-1];
```

`-1` will never be a valid index for a List, hence out of range error.

I assume you are trying to get the last element in the list, instead use [`list.last`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#last)